# Open Money Webhook hash validation in php through hmac

Tags: php, laravel-8, webhooks, hmac

i am tring to validate my openmoney webhook url but it is not working,i am getting all in $payload and then remove hash from $payload them convert it in string . and then hash_hmac but don't know what is problem ..

```
    $hashed_expected = $request->hash;

    $payload = $request->all();  // get all body 

    unset($payload['hash']);

    $str = json_encode($payload); // Convert in string

    $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str); // remove white space

    $service = DepositServices::where('type','open_money')->first();

    $apiSecret = $service->details->api_secret; // open money API Secret

    $hashed_value = hash_hmac('sha256',$string,$apiSecret);
   
    $data['hashed_value']=$hashed_value;

    $data['hashed_expected']=$hashed_expected;

    $data['string'] = $string;

    if (hash_equals($hashed_expected, $hashed_value) ) {
        $data['status'] = "Match";
       dd( $data);
    }else{
        $data['status'] = "Not Match";
        dd( $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating and comparing your hashed values, the payload needs to be identical as it was when the sender created and sent it. My guess is that the encoding and preg_replacing is mutating the payload.

Something like this should get you the original, unaltered payload body.

```
json_encode($request->all(), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```